# Azure Web App fails to locate appsettings.json after Visual Studio update

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have just updated my Visual Studio while working on a ASP.NET Core 1.1.1 project. Before the update my continuous delivery to Azure worked perfectly fine. Now I'm receiving an error when looking at the Web App after deployment. It is unable to find appsettings.json at the root location:

```
The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\appsettings.json'.
```

It is now looking for the file in the wwwroot folder. This is not the base path it was looking for before the update. I have **not** updated to ASP.NET Core 2.0.

My configurationbuilder looks like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
```

Is the appsettings.json file supposed to be moved or what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

In Azure, `wwwroot` is also a name for "base path" of your app where all dlls and app.config are placed. You site's "wwwroot" (with images, scripts and other) is subfolder, like `D:\home\site\wwwroot\wwwroot`. You can easily check this using [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-the-kudu-service).

Double-check changes to files after update, try run [`dotnet publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) locally - maybe something changed in your .csproj file and `applications.json` is not published anymore.